# put spaces between links

Tags: html

I have two questions:

1. When i run the code below, it shows me  names of links in large form, after i reload, it is good, so  what is problem?
2. I want to  put spaces between names  like this:

მთავარი  ბაკურიანი  გუდაური ზღვა  კახეთი   სვანეთი ვარძია ქართლი  ძველი_თბილისი

How could i do this?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <style>

    #links { 
      margin: 0 auto; 
      width: 3000px; 
      font-size:70px;
      clear: both; 
      display: block;
    }
    
    #test a {
      float: right;
    }
  </style>
  <body bgcolor="blue" >
    <a href="indexE.html"><img src ='english.gif' style="float:right"  width="88" height="88"> </a>
    <a href="indexR.html"><img src ='russian.gif' alt="Russian flag" style="float:right"  width="88" height="88"/>
    <a href="index.html"> <img src="georgian.jpg"  style="float:right" width="88" height="88"/>
    <div id="links">
      <a href=" index.html " >მთავარი </a>
      <a href=" ბაკურიანი.html ">ბაკურიანი </a>
      <a href=" გუდაური.html ">გუდაური </a>
      <a href=" ზღვა.html ">ზღვა </a>
      <a href=" კახეთი.html ">კახეთი </a>
      <a href=" სვანეთი.html ">სვანეთი </a>
      <a href=" ვარძია.html ">ვარძია </a>
      <a href=" ქართლი.html ">ქართლი </a>
      <a href=" ძველი_თბილისი.html ">ძველი_თბილისი </a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For question 2.): you could simply put a non breaking space in between:

```
<a href=" კახეთი.html ">კახეთი </a>
&nbsp;
<a href=" სვანეთი.html ">სვანეთი </a>
&nbsp;
<a href=" ვარძია.html ">ვარძია </a>
```

Which results in:

კახეთი 
 
სვანეთი 
 
ვარძია

Or you can add paddings/margins inside your style definitions so that anchors ("a tags") reserve some space to the left and/or right. The latte certainly is the preferred way to go.

Comment: Actually I did not understand question 1.)

Comment: imagine  that  name of  first link is main,when i run first time  page,it shows me main in large form,not like MAIN,but  height and width of letters are big,after reload page,it  returns it's small size

Comment: No idea, there is no reason for a changing font size in the definitions you posted here. Probably the best you can do is compare the styles applied to the links at runtime. Use a style debugger for this, for example Firebug for Firefox browser or the builtin versions for Chrome or IE. In there, select the link, then you are presented the exact style rules applied to the selected element. and, most important, these rules are grouped by the file and position they are defined in. This way you can find out which rule has the offending effect.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `&nbsp;` for space, it is a valid HTML string for space so it'll be validated by W3C too.

Answer (score 2):

use `&nbsp;` between links to get spaces

```
<a href=" index.html " >მთავარი </a>&nbsp;
<a href=" ბაკურიანი.html ">ბაკურიანი </a>&nbsp;
<a href=" გუდაური.html ">გუდაური </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

indexR and index need closing `</a>` tags.  Also for spaces use `&nbsp;` or css margins or padding.

Answer (score 0):

For using space in your html application use
    1) Entity name

> &nbsp

;
               Or
    2) Entity Number

> &#160

;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%20` the HTML-ASCII syntax for the space character. I have found that sometimes `&nbsp;` doesn't work that well **with links**.

Answer (score 0):

Add padding in anchor tag CSS file.

Directly applies to all anchor tag:

`ul li a{ padding: 10px; }`

Or if using any class then,

`.classname ul li a{ padding: 10px; }`

Answer (score 0):

Though `&nbsp` is totally valid but do try this as this is a elegant way

```
       <style>
       .links
       {
       display:flex;
       align-items:center;
      justify-content:space-around;
       }
      .links a
      {
      flex:1;
      text-align:center;
      }
       </style>

      <div class="links“>
        <a href=" კახეთი.html ">კახეთი </a>
      
       <a href=" სვანეთი.html ">სვანეთი </a>
       
       <a href=" ვარძია.html ">ვარძია </a>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How to make space between  exemple:        Home        About         Contact

```css
.menu{
      text-align: right; /*exemple*/
  }
  .menu1 {  
      list-style-type:  none;
        display: inline-flex;
    
    }


.test{
    color:red;
    text-decoration: none ;
    padding-inline-end: 55px; /*exemple */
    }
```

```html
<div class="menu">
            <ul class="menu1">
              <li><a href="#location" class="test">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#location" class="test">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#location" class="test">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```